Fail to run a Fastify/ts app compiled from typescript: ''TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'Serializer' of 'dependencies' as it is undefined.''
I develop an app with node.js Fastify framework (typescript, ES syntax). I decided to transpile files to CommonJS syntax to avoid incompatibilities in node environment. The app compiles from Typescript to JS successfully, but when I try to run the resulting app.cjs file, I get the following error:
backend/dist$ node app.cjs
/home/myzader/vc-app/backend/node_modules/fastify/lib/error-serializer.js:7
  const { Serializer, Validator } = dependencies
          ^

TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'Serializer' of 'dependencies' as it is undefined.
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/myzader/vc-app/backend/node_modules/fastify/lib/error-serializer.js:7:11)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1368:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1426:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1205:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1021:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1230:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:179:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/myzader/vc-app/backend/node_modules/fastify/lib/error-handler.js:20:24)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1368:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1426:10)

tsconfig.json:
  "extends": "@tsconfig/node20/tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "esnext",
    "allowJs": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "rootDir": "./",
    "strict": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true, 
    "noUncheckedIndexedAccess": true,     
    "noUnusedLocals": false,
    "resolveJsonModule": true
  },
  "include": [
    "./**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "**/*.spec.ts" // Exclude test files, if applicable
  ]
}

.babelrc:
{
  "presets": [
    ["@babel/preset-env", {
      "modules": "commonjs"
    }],
    "@babel/preset-typescript"
  ]
}

is it related to configs? Thank you!
